# Content API - parameter to find link url of a Link field

Tags: services

I have a custom content type called Link, which has a Link field. I'm using services and Content API to query the list of Links, and I want to show the data for a Link node where the Link is equal to a parameter passed into the URL.

Eg, I would like to do something like the following:

[Drupal root]/api/content?field_link=http://www.google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Content API](http://drupal.org/project/contentapi) is a tricky thing to get the hang of, but try to do the following:

As long as your Rest Server endpoint path is "api" and the resource is "content" what you have above should technically work.  Make sure you also enabled the Link content type in the Content API configuration.

When you do query with /api/content?field_link=http://www.google.com you will only get the base fields returned, even if you filtered by http://www.google.com it won't show in the response you get.  You then have to send another request to /api/content/ and that will return every field for that given node.

Hopefully this helps a little bit, if anyone can fill in my holes I would appreciate it, I'm by no means an expert, just played around with the Content API and got it to work a little.

I did respond to your email with some private links to prove that it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've just done a quick test, and it seems that if the query parameters don't find a match, then the whole result set is returned...It's annoying, but I can manage with that. Also, I wonder if anybody can find a way to filter the value of a Link content type.